# How do I show the current location in a Mapview using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In my scenario, I want to get the user's current location and show a pin on a map of that current location. I tried but I'm facing the issue below:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object( evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')

How do I resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RNLocation package to get user location I have shared the code with you. You just need to install that package.

```
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=> {
    RNLocation.configure({
        distanceFilter: 5.0
    })

    RNLocation.requestPermission({
        ios: "whenInUse",
        android: {
            detail: "coarse"
        }
    }).then(granted => {
        if (granted) {
            RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(locations => {
                setLocation(locations)
            })
        }
    })
},[])
```